# Build application for Ubuntu 18 from Ubuntu 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, glibc, cgo

I build my Go Application in my Ubuntu 20.04 OS with `go build -o myApp`.

When I run this app on Ubuntu Server 18.04, this error occurs:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./myApp)
```

As I searched in stackoverflow, someone mentioned installing `glibc 2.29` on the server. But someone else replied that this way is risky and may break OS.

Someone else suggested building App with `glibc 2.27`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Install Docker, and build inside an Ubuntu 18 container?

Comment: @tripleee Isn't there some easier option? I don't know docker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to make a static binary depends mostly on whether your code (or libraries) uses cgo.

If **cgo is not needed**, it's fairly easy: just disable it using the environment variable: `CGO_ENABLED`. This will automatically switch some cgo-based features to use pure go implementations ([netgo](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution), [osusergo](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#pkg-overview)):

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o myApp
```

If **cgo is required**, you can tell the linker to statically link C code as such:

```
go build -ldflags="-extldflags=-static" -o myApp
```

Note that not all cgo code will be happy about this. How to solve it depends on the libraries used.

Comment: Thanks.
Unfortunately, my project has 'webp' library that needs CGO. So I can't use this approach.

Comment: Ok, I've added a `cgo required` solution to my answer. Please try it out. I've also adjusted the non-cgo answer, only the environment variable is needed.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. It worked. Has there any potential errors in this solution?

Comment: If you get no compilation errors, you should be ok.

Comment: Worked. But, after 1 minute the application panics with lots of errors and then exists.

Comment: Hard to tell why without a panic message and probably a trace and some code. This might become a separate question though.

Comment: most of them has this header: goroutine 42145 [IO wait]

Comment: You're looking at the list of all goroutines. You want the panic message and the first goroutine listed. I recommend you open a separate question with debugging details and code.